# In which order GitLab services are started?

Tags: gitlab

In which order GitLab services are started?

Do they start in parallel or sequentially as defined in gitlab-ci file?

Could not find this information on the official GitLab site (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/gitlab.html)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: I disagree that it's off topic, it's been stated that continuous integration systems building programming projects are on-topic, though for the life of my I can't find where I've read that before.

Comment: Since the single runner running your job is starting the runners, they wouldn't be started in parallel, though I don't know what order they'd start in. I would assume it would be the order you specify in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. There is now a [GitLab Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab), so hopefully an employee or another user can answer better than I.

Comment: @AdamMarshall Thank you for your suggestion. I decided to go with an approach that does not depend on the order in which services are run.